# listening comprehension problems (British English)

Tags: listening

Fill in the blanks, please. And if you can, please explain the meanings of the words I'm missing.

1. http://vocaroo.com/i/s1fZBEslhzdA ...JPanel with a ScrollPane imbedded in it and a TextArea imbedded in the ScrollPane. Okay. So, let's take a look. What I wanna do is create a new class __________ that's gonna be the toolbar. So, this is a new custom component. (the rest is relevant) [sounds like "from start", but I can't make sense of it]
2. http://vocaroo.com/i/s1Y7DdYGZTZ4 Let's also alter that constructor a bit here because I might want to just ______ in the name and occupation here. Actually I'm not really sure about that.
3. http://vocaroo.com/i/s1dOdRZwTyyE To me, if your Mom is coming to visit this weekend for _______ and you say to me, "Graig, let's have a wild party this Saturday. Let's get some booze, let's get some drugs, let's invite some hot, sexy women." Which I never would, listeners. I would say, "But, Raza, what about your Mom?"

Comment: 1 Vaguely like "restore", but that's probably not it. It might help you guess, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Unsure on this one, do you have a source? Possibly: "with [Storm](https://storm.canonical.com/Tutorial)"
2. [bung](http://thefreedictionary.com/bung) - BrE - to sling/throw/chuck/toss - casually put in
3. [Fallas](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallas_de_Valencia) - Castillian Spanish or "Falles" in Catalan/Valencian.

Sources would help me (and others) be surer about these answers.

Comment: The course is on Java. Source: https://www.caveofprogramming.com/

Comment: Which tutorial?

Comment: They're not publicly available. They're unfortunately private. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: No worries. Does "Storm" make sense to you?

Comment: Make sense like what? Do I know about this system?

Comment: Okay, I know what you mean. I don't think he says "with Storm". Storm has nothing to do with that Java course.

Comment: I think he's naming the class. Is there anything like store/storm in the video or in the code?

Comment: @JMB I guess maybe, just maybe, the narrator referred to something looking like that thing before `com.example.android.snake` (under Snake > Android 2.0 > src in Package Explorer) in [this screenshot](http://www.caffeinedi.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Eclipse-IDE-with-Android-Sample-Project-Snake.png) as "star". :D